# Does StorageConnectionString in AzureWebjobSDK require access to the whole storage account?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobssdk

I'm trying to use Azure WebJobs SDK to trigger a function when a message is posted on a queue.

This works fine when setting StorageConnectionString to a connection string with the storage account key.

I would like to use a Shared Access Token (SAS) which has access to that queue (and only that) in the StorageConnectionString but getting errors:

> Message=Failed to validate Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK Storage
>   connection string. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection
>   string is not formatted correctly. Please visit
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758697.aspx for
>   details about configuring Microsoft Azure Storage connection strings.

And:

> ```
>    Message=The account credentials for '' are incorrect.
>    Source=Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
>    StackTrace:
>         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultStorageCredentialsValidator.<ValidateCredentialsAsyncCore>d__4.MoveNext()
> ```

The connection string I'm using is formatted this way:
BlobEndpoint=https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://myaccoount.queue.core.windows.net/queuename;SharedAccessSignature=token

Any chance StorageConnectionString requires access to the whole storage account? If so, do you have an idea what I could do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its possible to use SAS in a connection string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible to use SAS in a connection string. The question is whether Azure WebJob SDK allows using a SAS in the connection string which grants permissions to a queue only

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the WebjobSDK code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/dev/src it looks like the exception you are facing is thrown by the storage account parser. Looking at the code, it parses as follows:

```
    public static StorageAccountParseResult TryParseAccount(string connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount account)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            account = null;
            return StorageAccountParseResult.MissingOrEmptyConnectionStringError;
        }

        CloudStorageAccount possibleAccount;
        if (!CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out possibleAccount))
        {
            account = null;
            return StorageAccountParseResult.MalformedConnectionStringError;
        }

        account = possibleAccount;
        return StorageAccountParseResult.Success;
    }
```

I checked the formatting you sent using CloudStorageAccount and it seems to pass. Notice that you have an unnecessary '/' after the blob endpoint, maybe you are missing some text and that is causing the parsing to fail.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-configure-connection-string) to Configure Azure Storage Connection Strings. Occasionally I encountered the error as you mentioned: `The account credentials for '' are incorrect.`

As I known,  Azure WebJobs SDK would reference the Azure Storage client library, which is a wrapper of Azure Storage Service REST API. For troubleshooting the similar issue, you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network package. Here is the screenshot when I caught the above error via Fiddler:

[image]

> Any chance StorageConnectionString requires access to the whole storage account? If so, do you have an idea what I could do?

I assumed that there be something wrong with your connection string.

> QueueEndpoint=https://myaccoount.queue.core.windows.net/**queuename**

Here is my connection string that include an account SAS for blob and queue storage within my WebJob project, you could refer to it.

`<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="BlobEndpoint=https://brucechen01.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://brucechen01.queue.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sv=2015-12-11&amp;ss=bq&amp;srt=sco&amp;sp=rwdlacup&amp;se=2016-12-31T18:39:25Z&amp;st=2016-12-25T10:39:25Z&amp;spr=https&amp;sig={signature}" />`

**Note:** If you are specifying a SAS in a connection string in a configuration file, you may need to encode special characters in the URL via Html Encode.

**UPDATE:**

As you mentioned in the comment below `My SAS includes permissions to the queue with the "queuename" only`. Since you have configured SAS token for both Blob and Queue, I assumed that you need to create an account SAS token for blob and queue service. You could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to create the SAS token as follow:

Choose your storage account, right click and select "Get Shared Access Signature".

[image]

[image]

**Note:** When you replace the value of `SharedAccessSignature` with the generated SAS token, you need to remove the first `?` symbol in your SAS token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My SAS includes permissions to the queue with the "queuename" only. Did that scenario work for you?

Comment: I have tested this scenario and the request looks like this:  https://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/queuename/queuename?{sasToken}, then got the following error: "400 The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server". Per my understanding, `QueueEndpoint` is the base address for your queue storage, you couldn't configure it with the specific queue.

Comment: WebJob SDK provides you with a simple way to handle storage operations. For your scenario, you could discard WebJob SDK and try to leverage storage client library to implement the triggers for queue or blob by yourself. Also, you could post your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Thanks Bruce. What if I remove the queuename? 
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://myaccoount.queue.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=token
This still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please see my updates. I assumed that your SAS token is incorrect.