# azure function don't run locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to run my azure function locally

I have created a `local.setting.json` and added environment variables inside

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION":"10.14.1",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY":"b5277bdd-e284-44cbxxxxx",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=text2spexxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION":"~2",
    "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING":"xxxxxxx"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
}
```

But I get this error when I run the function using VSCode debugger

```
Exception: Worker was unable to load function texttospeechmain: 'Error: Credentials must be provided when creating a service client.'
```

Which credentials should I provide and where ?

Comment: Does this answer help? -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322863/does-storageconnectionstring-in-azurewebjobsdk-require-access-to-the-whole-stora

Comment: Can you show the code of your function?

Comment: Can you offer more information? To solve this problem needs more detials. Only offer the local setting is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging (in visual studio) I always set

"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

In my local.setting.json

Then when running locally it starts up the storage emulator automatically.

It may do the same in Vs code